# Data from join table is not being fetched

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

I have a relationship many-to-many and with that relationship, hibernate takes care of a join table. I have 2 entities: `Service` and `ServiceProvider`. The `Service` entity is the owning side, while the `ServiceProvider` is the non-owning side. When I fetch each entity by itself everything is fetched except the data from the join table (be it the `Service` or the `ServiceProvider` entity. I didn't create any special method to fetch the data, because I used the default Spring one, but after a while I created the one method to try and fetch a `Service` by its ID. And nothing works...The join table looks ok...Everything makes sense there, but when I try to fetch the data from the join table, the corresponding array is ALWAYS empty.

For example: for this url/API (ignore the nonconventional writing):

```
http://localhost:8080/getService/1 ← 1 is id of service
```

I get this response:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "serviceDescription": "Default service description1",
    "serviceProviders": []
}
```

Instead of:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "serviceDescription": "Default service description1",
    "serviceProviders": [
                     {
                         "id": 1,
                         "providerName": "provider1",
                         "services":[]
                     },
                     {
                          "id":2,
                          "providerName": "provider2",
                          "services":[]
                     }
                     {
                           "id":3
                           "providerName": "provider3",
                           "services":[]
                    }
]
}
```

Even though my join table looks like this:

```
service_id : service_provider_id
1                      1
2                      1
1                      2
1                      3
```

This is the method in question:

```
public Service findByID(long id){
        Optional<Service> service = serviceRepository.findByIdWithProviders(id);
        service.ifPresent(s -> s.getServiceProviders().size());

        System.out.println(service);
        return service.orElse(null);
    }
```

I'm all out of ideas...

NOTE: When I'm creating a new `Service` entity and connect an already preexisting `ServiceProvider` entity, as a return value I get the complete `Service` object. And that object contains the `ServiceProvider` object as it should. But once I try to fetch the `Service` object by itself, the `ServiceProvider` gets missing and the only thing I get in response is an empty array...

Here are the SQL queries I get from debugging:

```
Hibernate: select s1_0.service_id,s1_0.service_description,sp1_0.service_id,sp1_1.service_provider_id,sp1_1.provider_name from service s1_0 left join service_providers sp1_0 on s1_0.service_id=sp1_0.service_id left join service_provider sp1_1 on sp1_1.service_provider_id=sp1_0.service_provider_id where s1_0.service_id=?
Hibernate: select s1_0.service_provider_id,s1_1.service_id,s1_1.service_description from service_providers s1_0 join service s1_1 on s1_1.service_id=s1_0.service_id where s1_0.service_provider_id=?
Hibernate: select sp1_0.service_id,sp1_1.service_provider_id,sp1_1.provider_name from service_providers sp1_0 join service_provider sp1_1 on sp1_1.service_provider_id=sp1_0.service_provider_id where sp1_0.service_id=?
Hibernate: select sp1_0.service_id,sp1_1.service_provider_id,sp1_1.provider_name from service_providers sp1_0 join service_provider sp1_1 on sp1_1.service_provider_id=sp1_0.service_provider_id where sp1_0.service_id=?
Hibernate: select s1_0.service_provider_id,s1_1.service_id,s1_1.service_description from service_providers s1_0 join service s1_1 on s1_1.service_id=s1_0.service_id where s1_0.service_provider_id=?
Hibernate: select s1_0.service_provider_id,s1_1.service_id,s1_1.service_description from service_providers s1_0 join service s1_1 on s1_1.service_id=s1_0.service_id where s1_0.service_provider_id=?
Hibernate: select s1_0.service_provider_id,s1_1.service_id,s1_1.service_description from service_providers s1_0 join service s1_1 on s1_1.service_id=s1_0.service_id where s1_0.service_provider_id=?
```

Response:

```
Optional[Service(id=1, serviceDescription=Default service description1, serviceProviders=[])]
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, overriding the methods hashCode and equals fixed the problem...